# Unable to compile OpenSceneGraph for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, openscenegraph

I want to integrate OSG to my existing project. I have no previous experience in OSG, and I am following https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph as reference. However, though I update the paths and architectures for iOS 9.2, cmake fails at the first step itself. I am getting "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform". I am a newbie to cmake, any help would be deeply appreciated.